# Odd Numbered Cell Not Added To Pdf

Tags: asp.net, itext

I am trying to add `PdfPCell` inside a loop to a iTextSharp `Table` with 2 columns in a `Document`. But if the count inside the loop is an odd number. Then the last cell does not get added. Can someone please provide a solution to this problem? 

My code is below:

```
        var doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/QrCodes/") + fileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.WidthPercentage = 100;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (itemImages.Any(p => p.Reference == item.Reference) == true)
            {
                System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(@item.ItemQrCode));
                iTextSharp.text.Image pdfImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                PdfPCell cellImage = new PdfPCell(pdfImage);
                cellImage.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                cellImage.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                cellImage.Border = 0;

                table.AddCell(cellImage);

            }

        }

        doc.Add(table);
        doc.Close();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On your `PdfPTable` you can call the [`CompleteRow()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#completeRow%28%29) method when you're done and missing cells will be filled in.