# Not able to see other tables after pdf size limit

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have used iTextSharp to generate a PDF file.

I have created 6 `PdfPTable`s but it shows only 3.

```
// Create new PDF document 
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20f, 20f, 20f, 20f);
try {
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document,
        new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create));

    document.Open();
    int spacing = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

        table.TotalWidth = 144f;
        table.LockedWidth = false;
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("This is table" + i));
        cell.Colspan = 3;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1,
            document.Left + spacing, document.Top,
            writer.DirectContent);

        spacing = spacing + 200;
    }
}

catch (Exception ex) {}

finally {
    document.Close();
    ShowPdf(filename);
}
```

Here I have put the for loop for 6 times but it shows only 3 table.

[image: screenshot]

How can I show all 6 tables? I want to show only 3 table in 1 line after that break to new line and display other 3 tables.

Comment: I answered below however I also wanted to point out that you are looping while `i <= 6` which means you actually have 7 tables, not 6.

Comment: Yes. Sorry my mistake. Its actually 7 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the title of your question pretty much sums up the problem actually.

When you use `WriteSelectedRows` it is your responsibility to provide the X and Y locations to write to and you are drawing outside of the page boundaries. `A4` has 595 horizontal units and there's just not enough room. This is 100% valid however most people won't see it. I'm guessing that you want to "wrap" your table to the next line. There's a couple of ways of doing that:

**Bigger page size**

Switch to something like `PageSize.A0` and you should have more room. The page size is just a hint, anyway, print software will scale as needed.

**MOD check in loop**

This is the little more complicated one but every `n` tables you reset the `x` coordinate to the left edge and increase your `y` by the tallest of the previous row of tables.

```
int spacing = 0;
//The current Y position
float curY = document.Top;

//Well ask iText how tall each table was and set the tallest to this variable
float lineHeight = 0;

//Maximum number of tables that go on a line
const int maxPerLine = 3;

for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

    table.TotalWidth = 144f;
    table.LockedWidth = false;
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("This is table" + i));
    cell.Colspan = 3;
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
    table.AddCell(cell);

    table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1,
        document.Left + spacing, curY,
        writer.DirectContent);

    spacing = spacing + 200;

    //Set the height to whichever is taller, the last table or this table
    lineHeight = Math.Max(lineHeight, table.TotalHeight);

    //If we're at the "last" spot in the "row"
    if (0 == (i + 1) % maxPerLine) {
        //Offset our Y by the tallest table
        curY -= lineHeight;

        //Reset "row level" variables
        spacing = 0;
        lineHeight = 0;
    }
}
```

**Wrapper table**

This is what I really recommend. If you want to "wrap" tables then just use an outer table to hold your inner tables and you get everything for free and you don't have to mess with `DirectContent` (although you'll probably want to change table borders).

```
var outerTable = new PdfPTable(3);
outerTable.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;

for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {

    PdfPTable innerTable = new PdfPTable(2);

    innerTable.TotalWidth = 144f;
    innerTable.LockedWidth = false;
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("This is table" + i));
    cell.Colspan = 3;
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
    innerTable.AddCell(cell);

    outerTable.AddCell(innerTable);

}

document.Add(outerTable);
```

Comment: Perfect Explanation. In your 2nd approach (Wrapper table) : It shows only 6 tables due to `var outerTable = new PdfPTable(3);` but total is 7 table.
Now When i change the condition to `i<=8` then it shows the 9 tables.
So , i think our 2nd approach may be going to wrong in some situation like 7 tables etc.

Comment: iText doesn't "fill in the blanks" for you automatically but you can call [`CompleteRow()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17302895/231316) when you're done and it will fill with empty cells.

Comment: Thank You. Your explanation is very perfect.